# GWT: Adding Images in HighCharts

Tags: gwt, highcharts

I am developing a meteogram in GWT Highchart  like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/studies/meteogram.htm)

Adding series like this

```
            chart.addSeries(chart.createSeries()  
            .setName("")  
            .setType(Series.Type.SPLINE)
            .setPoints(new Number[]{  
                    2,7,3,6,9,0,7,5  })
```

But how can i Add Image to some series like in the image above 
and also how can i add these Grid Lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To render an image in the highchart you can use the Highcharts.Renderer class , 
specifically the image (String source, Number x, Number y, Number width, Number height)  method within this class. 
this method would help you to add an image from an external resource.

reference : http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#renderer

examples : http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/F4qS8/
           http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/ufUmg/

**EDIT**
for the grid try these options
http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#yAxis--gridLineWidth
http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--gridLineWidth

Comment: How did you do it in GWT Highcharts?

Comment: @austin If I want to render that image at an exact location to represent data say value 10 and 10 is in position (100,23) , how can we translate it to pixels. This 10 is not on the graph yet and never will be, the image is supposed to go there.